# TypeScript not following: has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
class Example {
    private server: string;
    constructor() {
        this.setServer();
    }
    setServer(): void {
        this.server = 'server';
    }
}

new Example();
```

Error:

```
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:309:13 - error TS2564: Property 'server' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

309     private server: string;
                ~~~~~~
```

Any reason why TypeScript isn't following?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't follow deeply and checks only constructor in case if someone overrides the `setServer` method and `initialization` will be removed.

You can use on of the next options:

- move it to the constructor
- add `!`.
- set default value
- make it optional

```js
class Example1 {
    private server: string;

    constructor() {
        this.server = 'server'; // <- here
    }
}
new Example1();

class Example2 {
    private server!: string; // <- here

    constructor() {
        this.setServer();
    }

    setServer(): void {
        this.server = 'server';
    }
}
new Example2();

class Example3 {
    private server: string = '';

    constructor() {
        this.setServer();
    }

    setServer(): void {
        this.server = 'server';
    }
}
new Example3();

class Example4 {
    private server?: string;

    constructor() {
        this.setServer();
    }

    setServer(): void {
        this.server = 'server';
    }
}
new Example4();
```

Comment: Also providing a default value, `private server = '';` would fit.

Comment: true, and also make it optional :) adding them.

Comment: Even with an explicit type `private server: string | undefined` which is the same as `private server?: string;`.